# How to add toggle button in menu item in android

Tags: android, menu, android-optionsmenu

I have options menu item in my application. Requirement was to add a toggle button to a menu item. Is this possible?

Answer (score 63):

As of this writing there are **3 options**.

**1)** Use `app:actionViewClass`. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Switch!"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**2)** You can use a custom layout in a menu item to add toggle button. Example:

Create a layout with [`Switch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) (alternatively, you may also use [`ToggleButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)), `res/layout/menu_switch.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="64dp" />
```

And use that layout in menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="@string/switch_button_title"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_switch"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**3)** You need to set `android:checkable` property of the menu to `true` and control its checked state in runtime. Example:

**Menu**:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/checkable_menu"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/checkable" />
```

**Activity**:

```
private boolean isChecked = false;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.checkable_menu);
    checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.checkable_menu:
            isChecked = !item.isChecked();
            item.setChecked(isChecked);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This provides a checkbox only.

Comment: A checkbox is essentially a toggle button: it toggles between two states :)

Comment: I could not see any checkbox :\

Comment: @Li3ro, please make sure that you have followed the steps correctly. This solution is working all the way to API level 22.

Comment: Well, According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html :      Note: Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the options menu) cannot display a checkbox or radio button. If you choose to make items in the Icon Menu checkable, you must manually indicate the checked state by swapping the icon and/or text each time the state changes. --- And this is exactly my case

Comment: See [this screenshot](https://lh4.ggpht.com/c0Cz5tQ7FpMfmjkBYJLWz7Ga9kXBd-wPS5gjCJZ3xjeDtRGEEFpFZGMqPxGpgNk3ANV0=h900): if the checkbox in the right top menu is not what you are talking about, then perhaps you should start a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400870/add-toggle-button-to-the-menu-to-stop-and-start-service/34760443#34760443

Comment: I don't see a checkbox

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: if you don't see the checkbox, perhaps, your problem is something else. So, please post a separate question.

Comment: I am trying to use the menu as a navigation-drawer menu. Maybe that menu has different rules?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere, works on my end with navigation drawer as well.

Comment: I read that the style can cause problems with it. I am using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 6):

I had a couple of issues when using a `actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch` in a menu item. It does actually show a switch on the `ToolBar`, although for me:

- The `onOptionsItemSelected()` doesn't actually get called when I toggle
  the switch.
- Using `setChecked()` on the `MenuItem` doesn't toggle its state.

Upon debugging and removing the `actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch`, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` gets called again.

Not sure what was going on; Maybe that I am using a custom `ActionBar` that I set using `setSupportActionBar()`, and using OptionsMenu callbacks within a **fragment** by enabling it with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.

I get this solved by inflating the switch itself, and set `OnCheckedChangeListener` on it

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/my_switch"
    android:title=""
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And in Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_switch);
    SwitchCompat mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) menuItem.getActionView();

    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        // Do something when `isChecked` is true or false
    });

}
```

And to toggle the switch programmatically, call `setChecked()` on the `Switch`, not on the `MenuItem`.

Comment: @thatGuy nice catch thank you!.. modified it now

Answer (score 2):

use app:actionViewClass

```
 <item android:id="@+id/id"
    android:title="@string/string"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ToggleButton"
    android:orderInCategory="80"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {       
      if(super.mMapView.isTraffic()) 
           menu.findItem(MENU_TRAFFIC_ID).setIcon(R.drawable.traffic_off_48); 
      else 
           menu.findItem(MENU_TRAFFIC_ID).setIcon(R.drawable.traffic_on_48); 

      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
 }
```

Comment: Icon I already have for menu items…I mean along with icon, title can I have a toggle button also? I need to save the toggle status..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to add a toggle button as one of the elements/items appearing in the options menu or add a button to a list item from the menu?

Then you can do it with a custom layout(use a `ListView` within if you want) and inflating it in the

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and you can save the values each time the button is toggles.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.btnToggleValue:
      // save it here
      return true;
    case R.id.btnSecond:
      ...
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```