# drawable states won't update on action bar

Tags: android

I have an action bar which contains an item `shuffle_action`.

I have used below case in the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function.

```
 switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_shuffle:
                    if(MusicService.shuffle) {
                        item.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(item.isChecked()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// returns false
                        musicService.clearShuffle();
                    }
                    else {
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(item.isChecked()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// returns true
                    }
                    musicService.setShuffle();
                    break;
    }
```

Now this thing works perfectly as i want it to work.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:icon="@drawable/shuffle_drawable"
        android:title="Shuffle"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        />
```

`shuffle_drawable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/shuffle_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_shuffle_black_18dp"/>
</selector>
```

The thing is that when the state changes the drawable won't change.Why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683186/menuitems-checked-state-is-not-shown-correctly-by-its-icon

Comment: yeah did that after half an hour of posting this question.Thanks though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MenuItem's checked state is not shown correctly by its icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683186/menuitems-checked-state-is-not-shown-correctly-by-its-icon)

Comment: You can check my answer as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400870/add-toggle-button-to-the-menu-to-stop-and-start-service/34760443#34760443