# Switch onCheckedChangedListner not registering clicks inside toolbar menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have a switch in my app toolbar to provide an option to the user to change the language.

[image: app toolbar]

When I am using the switch, the onCheckedChanged method is not working.
Further, it looks to me that onOptionsItemSelected is also not being hit as I don't see any log message on the screen.

Please note that the app is not crashing when I use the switch.

The clicks on options present inside the overflow menu are working properly. I am getting the log in those cases.

```
Switch aSwitch;
RelativeLayout langSwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

context = this;

// Removed non relevant code here. 
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d("tag_id",String.valueOf(id));
    langSwitch = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_switch);

    aSwitch = langSwitch.findViewById(R.id.langSwitch);

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (!b){
                //Language1 code
                Toast.makeText(context,"Language1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                //Language2 code
                Toast.makeText(context,"Language2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.savedPost){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SavedPost.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Below is my menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.app_name.android.app_name.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_switch"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title=""
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/savedPost"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:title="@string/saved_post" />

</menu>
```

This is my layout file for switch item.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/langSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textOff="@string/switch_text_off"
    android:textOn="@string/switch_text_on"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Additional information.

If I create another menu item (code below) with showAsAction 'always'  and click on this once, now when I use the switch the Toast message comes. I am clueless here as to why is it not happening for the first time. Also, how do I make it work without this menu item.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/english"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/switch_text_on"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: move your entire `aSwitch` code inside `onCreate()` method.. from find id to checkedlistener

Comment: @AbhishekSingh The app crashes with this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400870/add-toggle-button-to-the-menu-to-stop-and-start-service/34760443#34760443

Comment: ohh sorry your switch inside of menu.. my mistake..

Comment: @user3884753 check my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `inflate` an external layout over `ActionBar` that seems to first creating a `view` that holds your `ChildView` for your `layout`

**like Example**

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
item.addView(child);
```

**Try this in your code**

```
Switch aSwitch;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   View sw = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_switch).getActionView();
   aSwitch = (Switch) sw.findViewById(R.id.langSwitch);

   aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (!b){
            //Language1 code
            Toast.makeText(context,"Language1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            //Language2 code
            Toast.makeText(context,"Language2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(compoundButton.isChecked())

In boolean
```

Or

just try another version of `setonCheckedChangedListner`

Example:

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){@Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) { if (!compoundButton.isSelected()) { Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Selected"); invertLock(-1); } else { if (Utilities.isLockEnabled(context)) { Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Locked"); Utilities.showLockEnabled(context); } else { Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Locked"); invertLock(1); } } }
```