# Switch Button in popup menu android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

can someone please help me? I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, but I didn't find one.
I want to know how to do that you can press on a menu item(square number 1 in the picture), and then it opens up a popup menu(square number 2), and then it has an option with text and next to it a switch button(square number 3 in the picture)?

I didn't find an article/question that explains how to do a popup menu that has an option with a switch button. I would be very happy if someone can help me with this.
thanks a lot.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29SNx.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add some of your code? no one will be able to help you without you showing us some of the efforts that you have done from your side

Comment: do you want to display toggle button in your menu so, this article will be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282279/how-to-add-toggle-button-in-menu-item-in-android/21396305

Comment: Mustafa, the link you sent doesn't help me... That post talks about a toggle button as an item menu, I am looking for how to put a toggle button in a popup menu ...